# How do I make GraphQL API requests using fwconsole in FreePBX?

Tags: graphql, freepbx

FreePBX has a GraphQL API which allows us to make requests such as [the ones documented here](https://help.sangoma.com/community/s/article/PBX-GUI-Voicemail-module-GraphQL).

I would like to use the `fwconsole api` command to make these API requests at the command line.  There's no documentation for how to do this - the only forum post I could find was someone [asking exactly this question](https://community.freepbx.org/t/using-fwconsole-api-command/90559), and the post was closed automatically due to lack of responses.

I've tried things like

```bash
$ fwconsole api gql voicemail 'mutation { moduleOperations(input: { module: "voicemail", action: "enableVoiceMail", extensionId: "1081", password: "1234" }) { status message }}'
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `/usr/sbin/fwconsole ma mutation { moduleoperations(input: { module: "voicemail", action: "enablevoicemail", extensionid: "1081", password: "1234" }) { status message }} voicemail --'
```

and even-closer-to-their-api-docs:

```
$ fwconsole api gql voicemail 'mutation { enableVoiceMail(input: {extensionId: "1081", password: "1234" }) { status message }}'
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `/usr/sbin/fwconsole ma mutation { enablevoicemail(input: {extensionid: "1081", password: "1234" }) { status message }} voicemail --'
```

It looks like my output is being piped to the `fwconsole ma` subcommand somehow, though my attempts to trace through the code don't indicate why this would be the case.  Perhaps there's simply no way to do this at the command line?

Comment: Just from taking a quick look at the source, this doesn't seem to do what you think it does. It is strictly for working with module administration, and likely for internal use only if it isn't documented anywhere. If you want to call API endpoints from CLI, the usual route is with `curl` or `wget`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Freepbx API is a very limited REST interface.

For sure there is no GraphQL or anything fancy. Freepbx core is one from 200x, not new things.

All REST, GraphQL on FreePBX are just words. Most structures have zero support of even simple REST.

Some fields are missing, some MODULES are missing completely. Documentation is mess. You need the ability to read PHP complex code to use that API.

After adding extension you have issue "apply config" call to reload text files and asterisk core.

Generally speaking, it is much simpler to write directly to the database for most cases you can image.

Comment: Thanks, I have ended up going in the direction of "write directly to the database", since my findings were the same as yours.  I'm going to mark your answer as accepted, since I've come to the same conclusion, and if FreePBX later adds more functionality for the "fwconsole" command then I can accept a different answer at that time.

Comment: You can add that functionality yourself and submit a patch. Freepbx is now owned by Sangoma. Sangoma does not allow people to write patches for money anymore(to sign changes need key, they ask for sign agreement "no commercial use"). So it is unlikely someone will do that in next years.

Comment: There are two storages in Freepbx. If you not find something in MySQL db, check asterisk -rx "database show". And not forget to make "fwconsole reload" when you changed something(like put some flag in db and make reload by crontab if present)